# ActionView::TemplateError (Need controller and action!)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

*Never heard of this error in my three years of RoR.~*

I can't even debug this because it doesn't tell me how/why it's error'ing.

Any ideas?

**The Log**

```
Processing Admin::EmailsController#test_email (for 69.114.195.64 at 2011-08-17 08:52:00) [GET]
  Parameters: {"body"=>"null", "action"=>"test_email", "mail_type"=>"magic_email", "subject"=>"HQMagic Email... Surprise!", "controller"=>"admin/emails", "_"=>"1313596294081", "email"=>"daniel.levine4@gmail.com"}

ActionView::TemplateError (Need controller and action!) on line #25 of app/views/notifier/magic_email.html.haml:
22:       %div{:style => "clear:both;display:block;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0;"}
23:       .main-image{:style => "height: 262px;"}
24:         - if @email.main_deal_pic.url(:format) || @email.main_deal_pick_target
25:           = link_to image_tag(@email.main_deal_pic.url(:format), :style => "margin: 0 0 0 4px; display: block; border: 0;"), @email.main_deal_pic_target, :style => "border: 0;"
26:       %div{:style => "clear:both;display:block;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0;"}
27:       %img.header-middle{:src => "http://hqchannel.com/images/me-header-middle.jpg", :style => "display: block; margin: 0;"}
28:       %div{:style => "clear:both;display:block;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0;"}
```

Comment: what is `@email.main_deal_pic_target`?

Comment: It's the URL a user goes if they click on the @email.main_deal_pic . Both of them have valid data entries. The exact same data works on my testing.

Comment: try to replace it with: `(@email.main_deal_pic_target || "hey")`

Comment: Interesting, it looked like that bypassed the error. but now my URL says "hey" :D~ . Why do you think this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obviously your `@email.main_deal_pic_target` is `nil`. That's it.

As far as nobody knows how did you get `main_deal_pic_target` nobody can say why it is nil

**UPD**

Test it:

=  @email.main_deal_pic_target.inspect

Comment: Strange it isn't nil. It comes back in /console and on my production output as having an explicit link written. Equally, I have copied the same data object over to my local, and it works fine there.

Comment: Also I have a conditional statement asking if its nil or not, which it passes fine. So programmatically it knows there's content there, and it knows its a link. That link is added by a simple form where it asks you where you want this particular click to go. But I've updated it in /console to even blank, or nil, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then test it `@email.main_deal_pic_target.inspect`

Comment: returns => `""hqchannel.com/mariadavismyarbonnecom""`

Comment: So I copied over the exact same data to a new model, and it works perfectly. I'm curious if models can just go junk without explanation.

Comment: with double quotes? previusely it returns "hey" `(@email.main_deal_pic_target || "hey")` that means that it is nil

Comment: It can't. It means that it was just `nil`

Comment: Believe me, I'm just as boggled :D . It returns as a string so it already has quotes on it. But when you inspect a string, it will return as double quotes. And no, it was never nil. I checked that in /console as my first guess. I later *made* it nil programmatically just to see what would happen, but then I returned it to its original state.  Also, even if it had double quotes, it would probably still run, just not take you anywhere if you click it. I'm guessing..